# Iterating over column names in a data frame

Tags: r

In a loop, I am trying to perform a simple renaming of the variables in a df.

Without the loop, this works perfectly:

```
names(c1) <- c("sales", "month")
```

With a loop-friendly approach ("1" in place of i in the dry-run example) the following correctly references names(c1):

```
names(get(paste("c","1", sep="")))
```

but as I write the whole operation I get an error to the tune of "only the first element is used as variable name", here's the code:

```
assign(names(get(paste("c","1", sep=""))), c("sales", "month"))
```

I don't know what the error means, but no column title has been changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Roberto

Comment: Why don't you post your underlying problem? So far your questions suggest you have an inappropriate data structure for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: hadley, I have in fact followed your advice of correcting the data structure at the origin, so that I did not have to perform this operation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

According to the assign function's help, the first argument is the variable's name, given as a character string. No coercion is done, and the first element of a character vector of length greater than one will be used, with a warning

Answer (score -1):

`assign` takes a variable name as a string. `get` returns a variable, not its name.

In an attempt to taunt the R gods, here is a function that takes a string and a list of strings and assigns the list of strings to the name of the named data frame.

```
foo <- function(df, lon) {
  temp <- get(df)
  names(temp) <- lon
  assign(df, temp, inherits = TRUE)
}
```

There should be a way to do it without the copy.

Comment: *Shudder*.  Why not just pass in the object itself?  Working with names of objects is not a good strategy for success.

Comment: I agree.  I'm just trying to answer the question as asked.